# PHP Inheritance Question

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, class

If I have the following class:

```
class foo {
    function __construct() {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

And then use inheritance to create:

```
class bar extends foo {
    // Some code
}
```

When I instantiate class 'bar', will it automatically execute the __construct method from 'foo' or do I need to do something else to get that method to execute?

Comment: Have you tried it? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> Note:  Parent constructors are not
>   called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor.

While the documentation doesn't state it explicitly, the inverse of this sentence is also true, i.e., parent constructors are called implicitly if the child class does not define a constructor. Therefore, in your example, instantiating `bar` would call `foo::__construct` automatically.

Answer (score 2):

it works, the constructer from the parent class will be inherited.
if you define a new constructor in the instaciated class, it will override the constructor function of the parent class. if you still want to execute the parent constructer you should include

```
parent::__construct();
```

in the constructer of thje isntanciated class

Answer (score 1):

The `__construct` will carry over, yes.

The issue comes when you want to add something to that function, which is when the `parent` class comes in handy.

```
class bar extends foo {
    $this->doSomethingElse();
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course when you extend a class, the subclass inherits all of the public and protected methods from the parent class.